# Flutter - AppBar Bottom widget

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter

I wanted to ask, because I get a lot of errors, if it is possible to place a `Divider()` widget like this:

```
AppBar(
  bottom: Divider()
)
```

And if yes, could anyone show me how it's possible to do that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you read the `bottom` documentation, it must implement `PreferredSizeWidget` and `Divider` does not implement it.

But you can create your own version and use it there.

```
class MyDivider extends Divider implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  MyDivider({
    Key key,
    height = 16.0,
    indent = 0.0,
    color,
  })  : assert(height >= 0.0),
        super(
          key: key,
          height: height,
          indent: indent,
          color: color,
        ) {
    preferredSize = Size(double.infinity, height);
  }

  @override
  Size preferredSize;
}
```

Comment: Could you tell what is not working? If I do AppBar(title: Text("Title"), bottom: MyDivider(color: red) ) I can see a one pixel red line in the bottom of my bar.

Comment: Really maybe I'll try it one more

Answer (score 11):

*try this...*

```
bottom: PreferredSize(
      child: Container(
         color: Colors.orange,
         height: 4.0,
      ),
      preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(4.0)),
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can add `Divider()` to AppBar bottom.

```
bottom: const PreferredSize(
  preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(1),
  child: Divider(height: 1),
)
```